# Flutter: A horizontal ListView that selects items like a ListWheelScrollView

Tags: flutter

I would like to create a scrolling selection widget in Flutter that looks like a horizontal `ListView` but acts much like a `ListWheelScrollView` in that it uses `FixedExtentScrollController` and emits a selection event (callback) for the child scrolled into the center of the list. Especially the list should only allow scrolling by multiples of the size of its children (which are all the same size) and keep one child at the center of the view, even if there are no other children to the right or left.

Is there anything like this out there or do I have to roll my own?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the `Carousel` widget from [getwidget](https://pub.dev/packages/getwidget) which can be configured to meet my requirements.